# How do galaxies cross our particle horizon?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, universe, observable-universe

At the begin of his lecture "The Quantum Origin of the Universe" (2014) James Hartle makes the following statement:
"A new galaxy with a 100 billion stars becomes visible - ie comes across the horizon - every 10 minutes as the universe expands."
How do you get to this conclusion? How do you calculate this?
(I know that the particle horizon expands with 3.2c)

Answer (score 1):

It may just be an error. The naive method of calculating the rate of change of the number of galaxies should give the correct answer: in a short time $δt$ the number of galaxies increases by a factor of $(R+v\,δt)^3/R^3$, where $R \approx 46 \text{ Gly}$ and $v \approx 3.2 c$. Using his figure of 100 billion visible galaxies from [the same slide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kvFyu7A8o7E&t=176s) and rounding to order of magnitude, the rate of increase is about one per 10 days, not per 10 minutes.

Comment: When doing the calculation I get a value for delta-t around a million years. I think you neglected the cube of v.delta-t and R to obtain your much lower result.

Comment: @ReneKail I used $(R+v\,δt)^3/R^3 = (1+v\,δt/R)^3 \approx 1+3v\,δt/R$. So if there are $N$ galaxies at time $t$ then there are $N+1$ at $t+R/(3vN)$ approximately.

Comment: Thank you, that's correct. I found a mathematical flaw in my calculation, so I had to redo it. Moreover, I got your result also when introducing the number density of galaxies. Result: delta-t is about 10 days.